# Swift viewController still loads for long time when using multithreading

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I am trying to load a UIViewController first then update UI after the data has completed loading in a background thread (I think this is basic knowledge of multithreading).

So the view controller will get an attributed string from a function of an item because this function has for loop so I put the for loop in a background thread then after it finished call the closure, but when I test it, I tap the item, then the app freezes for a while then goes to the view controller after the data has been loaded, I don't know where to fix this problem

This is the function that viewController is calling in viewDidLoad()

```
public func getPeriodicalCompletionInAttributedString(font: UIFont, normalColor: UIColor, redColor: UIColor, greenColor: UIColor, grayColor: UIColor, finish: @escaping (NSMutableAttributedString) -> Void) {
    var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let everyWeek: EveryWeek = self.newFrequency as! EveryWeek
    let currentWeekDates: Array<CustomDate> = CustomDate.current.weekDates
    var punchedInDaysInCurrentWeek: Int = 0

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        for punchInDate in self.punchInDates { // Get Check In days in current week with all stored check in dates
           if currentWeekDates.contains(punchInDate) {
                 punchedInDaysInCurrentWeek += 1
           }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // call closure after calculating check in days completed
           let attribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: normalColor]
           attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(punchedInDaysInCurrentWeek) / \(everyWeek.days)", attributes: attribute)
           finish(attributedString)
        }
    }
}
```

And This is how I call it in ViewController

```
self.todayLabel.text = ""
// add loading animation first
LoadingAnimation.add(to: self.todayLabel, withRespondingTime: 10, circleWidth: 2, circleRadius: 10, timeOutAlertTitle: "Timeout")
self.item.getPeriodicalCompletionInAttributedString(font: self.todayLabel.font, normalColor: .label, redColor: ThemeColor.red.uiColor, greenColor: ThemeColor.green.uiColor, grayColor: self.setting.grayColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5)) { result in
    self.todayLabel.attributedText = result
    LoadingAnimation.remove()
    //Remove loading animation after data has loaded
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure you are specifying your font name properly. Improperly named fonts are a known source of performance issues as the system searches to find the correct match

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954956/why-uifontdescriptorsize-is-x200-slower-than-uifontnamesize Try removing the font from your attributes string and see if that is the issue. Also use the time profiler instrument

Comment: I found out what's going on, it's because there is another component in this view controller calling a function that needs a large amount of calculation, and I modified this function to calculate in backend thread, still thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"App freezes for a while then goes to the view controller"*, this is usually caused by code located in "viewWillAppear". Try moving some of the "viewWillAppear" code to "viewDidAppear" and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, I found out what's going on, it's because there is another component in this view controller calling a function that needs a large amount of calculation, and I modified this function to calculate in background thread, still thank you for your solution!